How to make this tikzpicture fit on single pdf page?
I want to generate single page pdf for the tikzpicture as I will include this pdf as image using inlcudegraphics.
I looked at Fitting page size to a tikz figure  but when I try the solution there, which is to use \documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone} my file do not compile using lualatex. it gives
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Dimension too large.
\orig@pgf@shape@interpictureshift ...f@y =\pgf@ya
                                                  \fi
l.279 ...ea.south west)},scale=0.75,transform shape]

If I use \documentclass[12pt]{article} then it compiles OK, but the pdf generated has 2 PDF pages. The first page is empty, and the second page has the tikz pic. This causes problems later on.
How do I solve this? I do not want to include this code in my main document, but want to make it standalone and compile it separately and just use the generated PDF as image in my main document.
I also do not want to use Tikz' external library as I had problems with it.
The code is long, but here it is (link to source code at bottom also).
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%this does not work
%\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{float} 

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\ifdefined\HCode 
\else 
\newcommand\NODEWIDTH{4cm} 

\newcommand\firstOrder{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright  
First order ODE
\begin{align*} 
f(x,y,y')&=0
\end{align*} 
    \end{minipage}   
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderDegreeNotOne{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
First order with nonlinear $y'$
\begin{align*} 
f(x,y,y')&=0
\end{align*} 
\end{minipage}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderDegreeOne{
\begin{minipage}{10cm}\raggedright  
First order ODE where $y'$ is linear  $f(x,y,y')=0$
\end{minipage}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderQuadrature{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
Solved by integration
{\begin{align*} 
y'&=f(x)\\
y&=\int{f\,dx}+c
\end{align*} 
}
\end{minipage}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\newcommand\firstOrderLinear{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright 
\footnotesize    
Linear. Solved by finding an integrating factor.
{\begin{align*} 
y'+f(x) y = g(x)
\end{align*}  
}
\end{minipage}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderSeparable{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize 
Separable. Solved by separation and
then integration.
{\begin{align*} 
y' &= F(x,y)\\
   &= f(x)g(y)
\end{align*} 
}
\end{minipage}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderBernoulli{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
Bernoulli $ y'+P y=Q y^n$ where $n\neq 1,n\neq 0$. 
Solved using substituion $v=y^{1-n}$ which converts
the ode to linear one $v'+(1-n)P v=(1-n) Q$.              
\end{minipage}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderHomogeneousA{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
Homogeneous type A.
{\begin{align*} 
y'&=f\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) 
\end{align*}}                 
Solved using substitution $y=ux$ which converts to 
separable ode.
\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderHomogeneousC{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
Homogeneous type C. ODE has the form
\begin{align*} 
y'&=\left(a + b x + y\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
y'&=\left( a + b x + y\right)^{n}
\end{align*}
Where $n$ is integer not one. Solve by substitution $z=\left(a + b x + y\right)$.
See \href{http:12000.org/my_notes/first_order_nonlinear_ode/index.htm}{example}
\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderHomogeneousMapleC{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
This is called homogeneous type Maple C. This is different from
what is called just homogeneous type C above. ODE has the form
\begin{align*} 
y'&=\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}
\end{align*}
Solved using transformation
$x=X+x_0, y=Y+y_0$ to convert to homogeneous type A. See \href{https://12000.org/my_notes/solving_isobaric_ode/index.htm}{this}
\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderExact{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
Exact. ODE has the form
\begin{align*} 
y'&=\frac{-M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}
\end{align*}
Or as typically written
\begin{align*} 
M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy &= 0
\end{align*}
Where $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$
\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderExactWithIntegratingFactor{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
Not Exact, but can find integrating factor which makes it
exact. ODE has the form
\begin{align*} 
y'&=\frac{-M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}
\end{align*}
Or as typically written
\begin{align*} 
M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy &= 0
\end{align*}
Where $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \neq \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$
but can find integrating factor $\mu$ such that 
$\frac{\partial (\mu M)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial (\mu N)}{\partial x}$
\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderRiccati{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
Riccati. ODE has any of these forms
\begin{align*} 
y'&=f_0(x)+f_1(x)y+f_2(x)y^2\\
y'&=f_0(x)+f_2(x)y^2
\end{align*}
Where $f_0\neq 0$. An example if $y'=x^2-y^2$. Solved by 
using transformation $y=\frac{u'}{f_2 u}$ which generates
second order ode in $u$ to solve.
\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderIsobaric{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
Isobaric. Generalization of homogeneous where the substitution $y=v x^m$  
makes the ODE separable. The weight $m$ here need not be $1$ as the case with homogeneous.
An example is $2x^3 y'=1+\sqrt{1+4x^2 y}$ where weight $m=-2$ here and 
$y=v x^(-2)$ makes the ode separable. 
\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderFormIDOne{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
Special form called SpecialFormIDOne for ode of form
\begin{align*} 
y'&=g(x)e^{a(x)+by}+f(x)
\end{align*}
Solved by substitution $u=e^{-b y}$ which converts the ode
to linear. $b$ must not depend on $x$.
\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderPolynomial{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
Polynomial ode. ODE of the form
\begin{align*} 
y'&=\frac{a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1}{a_2 x + b_2 y + c_2}
\end{align*}
Where the two lines can be either parallel or not.
\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderAbelFirstKind{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
Abel first kind. ODE of the form
\begin{align*} 
y'&=f_0(x)+f_1(x)y\\
    &+f_x(x)y^2+f_3(x)y^3
\end{align*}
Currently the solver detect this ODE and evaluates the Abel invariant only.
\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderDifferentialType{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
First order differential type. These are special 
ode's which can written as complete differential  $d(f(x,y))=d(g(x,y))$
which is then solved by just integrating. For an example
$y'=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$ can be written $y\,dy=d\left( \frac{1}{2}x^2-xy\right)$
which is now solved by integrating both sides. See
\href{https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501368/what-is-wrong-with-solving-this-ode-using-this-method}{this} 
\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderSeries{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
First order $q(x) y'+ r(x) y = f(x)$ solved using series method. Submethods supported
are
\begin{enumerate}
\item Irregular singular point
\item Ordinary point
\item Ordinary point Regular singular point
\end{enumerate}
Expansion around point other than zero is also supported, including initial conditions.
\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\firstOrderLaplace{
\begin{minipage}{\NODEWIDTH}\raggedright     
\footnotesize
First order ode $q(x) y'+ r(x) y = f(x)$ solved using Laplace method.
\end{minipage}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fi 

\begin{document}

%linear in y' flow chart 
\ifdefined\HCode 
\else 
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle,   draw=red,  text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, color=blue!60, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [ circle,draw,fill=yellow!20, minimum width=1cm]
\fi 

\begin{tikzpicture}[shift={(current page text area.south west)},scale=0.75,transform shape]    
%    
%\draw[help lines, dashed] (0,0) grid (current page text area.north east);
    \coordinate (O) at  (8,22);
    \node [block, minimum width=14cm] at (O) (firstOrderDegreeOne) {\firstOrderDegreeOne};
    %
    \node [block, below left=.3cm and -4.7cm of firstOrderDegreeOne] (firstOrderQuadrature) {\firstOrderQuadrature};
%
    \node [block, below =.3cm of firstOrderQuadrature] (firstOrderLinear) {\firstOrderLinear};
    \node [block, below =.3cm of firstOrderLinear]  (firstOrderSeparable){\firstOrderSeparable};
    \node [block, below =.3cm of firstOrderSeparable]  (firstOrderHomogeneousA){\firstOrderHomogeneousA};
    \node [block, below=.3cm of firstOrderHomogeneousA]   (firstOrderHomogeneousC) {\firstOrderHomogeneousC};
    \node [block, below=.3cm of firstOrderHomogeneousC]   (firstOrderHomogeneousMapleC) {\firstOrderHomogeneousMapleC};
    \node [block, below=.3cm of firstOrderHomogeneousMapleC]   (firstOrderBernoulli) {\firstOrderBernoulli};
%second column
                                      %more negative moves to right
    \node [block, below left=.3cm and -9.9cm of firstOrderDegreeOne] (firstOrderExact) {\firstOrderExact};
    \node [block, below=.3cm of firstOrderExact]   (firstOrderExactWithIntegratingFactor) {\firstOrderExactWithIntegratingFactor};
    \node [block, below=.3cm of firstOrderExactWithIntegratingFactor]   (firstOrderRiccati) {\firstOrderRiccati};
    \node [block, below=.3cm of firstOrderRiccati]   (firstOrderIsobaric) {\firstOrderIsobaric};
    \node [block, below=.3cm of firstOrderIsobaric]   (firstOrderFormIDOne) {\firstOrderFormIDOne};
%third column
    \node [block, below left=.3cm and -15cm of firstOrderDegreeOne] (firstOrderDifferentialType) {\firstOrderDifferentialType};
    \node [block, below=.3cm of firstOrderDifferentialType]   (firstOrderPolynomial) {\firstOrderPolynomial};
    \node [block, below=.3cm of firstOrderPolynomial] (firstOrderSeries) {\firstOrderSeries};
    \node [block, below=.3cm of firstOrderSeries]   (firstOrderAbelFirstKind) {\firstOrderAbelFirstKind};
    \node [block, below=.3cm of firstOrderAbelFirstKind] (firstOrderLaplace) {\firstOrderLaplace};

%first column
    \path [line] (1.15,21.5)   |- (firstOrderQuadrature.west);
    \path [line] (1.15,21.5)   |- (firstOrderLinear.west);
    \path [line] (1.15,21.5)   |- (firstOrderSeparable.west);
    \path [line]  (1.15,21.5) |- (firstOrderHomogeneousA.west);
    \path [line]  (1.15,21.5) |- (firstOrderHomogeneousC.west);
    \path [line]  (1.15,21.5) |- (firstOrderHomogeneousMapleC.west);
    \path [line]  (1.15,21.5) |- (firstOrderBernoulli.west);
%second column
    \path [line]  (5.95,21.5) |- (firstOrderExact.west);
    \path [line] (5.95,21.5) |- (firstOrderExactWithIntegratingFactor.west);
    \path [line]  (5.95,21.5) |- (firstOrderRiccati.west);
    \path [line] (5.95,21.5) |- (firstOrderIsobaric.west);
    \path [line] (5.95,21.5) |- (firstOrderFormIDOne.west);    
%third column
    \path [line] (11.4,21.5) |- (firstOrderDifferentialType.west);
    \path [line] (11.4,21.5) |- (firstOrderSeries.west);
    \path [line] (11.4,21.5) |- (firstOrderAbelFirstKind.west);
    \path [line] (11.4,21.5) |- (firstOrderLaplace.west);
    \path [line] (11.4,21.5) |- (firstOrderPolynomial.west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The command to compile is lualatex image_1.tex
This is the pdf generated

TL 2024. I've also put the .tex file and the PDF file in this folder if it is easier to download.

That's a lot of code. If you're using current page text area you must use remember picture and most likely, in your case, also overlay (doesn't seem like you use the page for anything else). The content of the TikZ picture might protrude into the margin or outside of the page itself but it will not move around anymore.

Eliminar class=minimalin option standalone and shift={(current page text area.south west)}

Why don't you want to use the code and take an image of the output instead? Wouldn't that make the links you included inaccessible?

Like this:

Your question is not entirely clear. Why you define contents of nodes as commands containing minipage and not write contents directly in node as is done in MWE below? Doing such code is much simpler, shorter and clearer and works fine also at using of the standalone  document class:
\documentclass[margin=3mm, vartwidth=160mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{angles,  arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                matrix,
                positioning,
                quotes}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\renewcommand{\abovedisplayskip}{2pt} 
%\renewcommand{\belowdisplayskip}{2pt} 
%\usepackage{float} 
%\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
%shift={(current page text area.south west)},scale=0.75,transform shape
node distance = 2mm,
  start chain = going below,
   arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, semithick, blue},
   box/.style = {draw=red, rounded corners, 
                 minimum height=9mm, text width=#1,
                 font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                 on chain},
 box/.default = \dimexpr\textwidth/3-7mm
                        ]    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\node (n0)  [box=\textwidth, align=center] 
            {First order ODE $f(x,y,y') = 0$};
%%%% first column
\node (n11) [box, below right=3mm and 4.4mm of n0.south west] 
            {Solved by integration
                \begin{align*} 
            y'  & = f(x)\\
            y   & = \int{f\,dx}+c
                \end{align*}
            };
\node (n12) [box] 
            {\textbf{Linear.}
             Solved by finding an integrating factor.
                \[  
             y'+f(x) y = g(x)
                \]  
            };
\node (n13) [box] 
            {\textbf{Separable.} 
             Solved by separation and then integration.
                \begin{align*} 
            y' & = F(x,y)\\
               & = f(x)g(y)
                \end{align*}
            };
\node (n14) [box] 
            {\textbf{Homogeneous type A.}
                \[
            y' = f\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) 
                \]              
            Solved using substitution $y=ux$ which converts to separable ODE.
            };
\node (n15) [box] 
            {\textbf{Homogeneous type C.}
             ODE has the form
                \begin{align*} 
            y' & = (a + b x + y)^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
            y' & = (a + b x + y)^{n}
                \end{align*}
            Where $n$ is integer not one. Solve by substitution $z=(a + b x + y)$.
            See \href{http:12000.org/my_notes/first_order_nonlinear_ode/index.htm}{example}
            };
\node (n16) [box] 
            {\textbf{Homogeneous type Maple C.} This is different from
             what is called just homogeneous type C above. ODE has the form
                \[
            y' = \frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}
                \]
            Solved using transformation $x=X+x_0$, $y=Y+y_0$ 
            to convert to homogeneous type A. See \href{https://12000.org/my_notes/solving_isobaric_ode/index.htm}{this}
            };

\node (n17) [box] 
            {\textbf{Bernoulli}  $y'+P y=Q y^n$ where $n\neq 1,n\neq 0$. 
            Solved using substituion $v=y^{1-n}$ which converts the ODE to linear one $v'+(1-n)P v=(1-n) Q$. 
            };             

%%%% second (midle) column
\node (n21) [box, below=3mm of n0] 
            {\textbf{Exact.}
             ODE has the form
                \begin{gather*} 
                y' = \frac{-M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}
                \shortintertext{Or as typically written}
            \begin{multlined}[b]
                M(x,y)dx\\+N(x,y)dy
            \end{multlined} 
                    = 0
                \end{gather*}
            Where $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$
            };
\node (n22) [box] 
            {\textbf{Not Exact}, but can find integrating factor which makes it exact. ODE has the form
                \begin{gather*} 
            y' = \frac{-M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}
             \shortintertext{Or as typically written}
            \begin{multlined}[b]
                M(x,y)dx\\+N(x,y)dy
            \end{multlined} 
                    = 0
                \end{gather*}
            Where $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \neq \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$ but can find integrating factor $\mu$ such that $\frac{\partial (\mu M)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial (\mu N)}{\partial x}$
            };
\node (n23) [box] 
            {\textbf{Riccati.} ODE has any of these forms
                \begin{align*} 
            y' & = \begin{multlined}[t]
                    f_0(x)+f_1(x)y\\+f_2(x)y^2
                    \end{multlined}    \\
            y' & = f_0(x)+f_2(x)y^2
                \end{align*}
            Where $f_0\neq 0$. An example if $y'=x^2-y^2$. Solved by 
            using transformation $y=\frac{u'}{f_2 u}$ which generates
            second order ODE in $u$ to solve.
            };
\node (n24) [box] 
            {\textbf{Isobaric.} 
             Generalization of homogeneous where the substitution $y=v x^m$  makes the ODE separable. The weight $m$ here need not be $1$ as the case with homogeneous. An example is $2x^3 y'=1+\sqrt{1+4x^2 y}$ where weight $m=-2$ here and $y=v x^(-2)$ makes the ODE separable. 
            };
\node (n25) [box] 
            {\textbf{SpecialFormIDOne} 
             ODE of form
                \[
            y' = g(x)e^{a(x)+by}+f(x)
                \]
            Solved by substitution $u=e^{-b y}$ which converts the ODE to linear. $b$ must not depend on $x$.
            };           
%%%% third column
\node (n31) [box, below left=3mm and 4.4mm of n0.south east] 
            {\textbf{First order differential type.} These are special ODE's which can written as complete differential  $d(f(x,y))=d(g(x,y))$ which is then solved by just integrating. For an example $y'=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$ can be written $y\,dy=d\left( \frac{1}{2}x^2-xy\right)$ which is now solved by integrating both sides. See
\href{https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501368/what-is-wrong-with-solving-this-ode-using-this-method}{this} 
            };
\node (n32) [box] 
            {\textbf{Polynomial ODE.} 
            ODE of the form
                \[
            y' = \frac{a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1}{a_2 x + b_2 y + c_2}
                \]
            Where the two lines can be either parallel or not.
            };
\node (n33) [box] 
            {First order $q(x) y'+ r(x) y = f(x)$ solved using series method. Submethods supported are
                \begin{enumerate}[nosep, leftmargin=*]
            \item Irregular singular point
            \item Ordinary point
            \item Ordinary point Regular singular point
                \end{enumerate}
            Expansion around point other than zero is also supported, including initial conditions.
            };
\node (n34) [box] 
            {\textbf{Abel first kind.}
            ODE of the form
                \begin{align*} 
            y' & = f_0(x)+f_1(x)y\\
               & + f_x(x)y^2+f_3(x)y^3
                \end{align*}
            Currently the solver detect this ODE and evaluates the Abel invariant only.
            };
\node (n35) [box] 
            {First order ODE $q(x) y'+ r(x) y = f(x)$ solved using Laplace method.
            };
%%% lines

\coordinate (a) at ([xshift=2mm] n0.south west);
\coordinate (b) at ([xshift=2mm] n11.east |- n0.south);
\coordinate (c) at ([xshift=2mm] n21.east |- n0.south);
\draw[arr] (a) |- (n17);
\draw[arr] (b) |- (n25);
\draw[arr] (c) |- (n35);
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}    \draw[arr]  (a |-n1\i) |- (n1\i);
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}    \draw[arr]  (b |-n2\i) |- (n2\i);
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}    \draw[arr]  (c |-n3\i) |- (n3\i);
    \end{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}

In the case, that you like to use article document class, you need to define sufficient large page layout that image can be fit on page and a wee bit redefine options for box node style. For example:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{angles,  arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                matrix,
                positioning,
                quotes}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \noindent%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm,
  start chain = going below,
   arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, semithick, blue},
   box/.style = {draw=red, rounded corners, 
                 minimum height=9mm, text width=#1,
                 font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                 on chain},
 box/.default = \dimexpr\textwidth/3-9mm  % <---
                        ]    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\node (n0)  [box=\textwidth, inner xsep=0pt, align=center] 
            {First order ODE $f(x,y,y') = 0$};
%%%% first column
...

With this changes the resulted picture is the same as before.

Nice. However I don't get the same output. I need to change the offset of (n11) and (n31) 4.4mm to 3.5mm to match the box\.default -7mm. I propose to replace in (n0) align=center by \centering...\par and in (n24) x^{-2}. The library angles,calc,matrix,quotes are not used. And varwidth in option class. As usual, I learn a lot by looking at your code.

@pascal974, you are right that MWE has samo mismatch , When upload MWE I mixed solution for use of the standalone and article document class. Now the code is corrected and added some more explanation.
